# Generic state management function flow type react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

I have a question on how to make a generic state updater

```
type State = {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    contactInfo: ContactInfo
}
```

and in my component

```
onChangeField = (field: $Keys<State>) => (value: $ElementType<State, field>) => {
    this.setState({ [field]: value });
}
```

I'm getting an error cannot use literal 'contactInfo' as type because string literal 'contactInfo' is a value.

You can check in try flow playground [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuYASgKYCGAxkVHnJmAOR4XWMDcqqBAntqWADCcAHYEqBAJIiocMAF4wAb1Rgw2ABajSALjAiArpgBGpPABpVYUpnLoYegM4E86EQHNUAX07c+AgGVxAgFFFTU1EXJMXTBnVw9LCLByd1jDEzMkiMpRcWppWT1hMQlCuG9fXn4wAAU6bEcFZR8uShhyRyaAWR5hHG0xawAPEJEAEyayCQA6ftwRUjEAHnq4RvMwIPIQgD5lK1FBDXIPUgAxdFIYceaACigrm70AEgBpUh5HZe29gEoFPs7gA3cgwAyxF4AURgNiWBAAKv4fsFSJtHtdxrsAfJ9uFkmACBp0I4Zo5SARfqQ7kowABtDE3AC6elB4IEXj+nDUXi4ahYEzMdwB+P5FIMeBEYDuy3G6GBuyUACJemBcjhFmIlV5lsA5QquVZeV4gA)

Comment: `(field: $Keys<State)` should be `(field: $Keys<State>)` but I'm not sure if this is going to solve your error

Comment: (Sidenote: This would be easier to debug if you make an example on https://flow.org/try/ . You can even use react there)